# Cryptsharp C# Visual Studio 2022 no definition

Tags: c#, visual-studio, md5, cryptsharp

I've tried to run

```
string cryptedPassword = Crypter.MD5.Crypt(Passwort, new CrypterOptions()
         {
            {CrypterOption.Variant, MD5CrypterVariant.Apache}
         });
```

from the [cryptsharp documentation](https://documentation.help/CryptSharp/a180b4f5-7de3-658d-7c36-9b4bc0f6cdc4.htm)

But I don't seem to be able to run it.

`Passwort` is a random 5 char string

I have this code:

```
using System; using CryptSharp;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
```

but keep running into errors:

> Crypter has no definition for MD5
> MD5CrypterVariant not available

What am I missing ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `Passwort`? Is it definitely a byte array?

Comment: What Nuget package and Framework are you running? This code works for me using 4.7.2 and CryptSharpOfficial https://dotnetfiddle.net/jE6C1y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use MD5 crypt algorithms, we need to install the following NuGet packages.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/CryptSharpOfficial/

[image]

Here is my code:

[image]

If there are still errors, you can try to reinstall the NuGet packages.